# Retrieving a mobile app title, description, icons from app stores using its ID in Javascript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps, google-play, app-store

Let's assume following scenario:

- we are providing web pages for our customers (say CMS).
- customers themselves have mobile
  apps which they want to get promoted on phones accessing pages
  we generate for them (HTML5, JS).
- we want to avoid redundancy and thus we would like to use
  *only* apps IDs to retrieve apps' titles, descriptions, icons directly from
  app stores.
- **However, we do not want to implement any authentication/authorization logic since we assume all the data
  mentioned are publicly available.**

To sum up, "input" is a mobile app ID (targeted platform is known), and the "output" is app's title, description, icons gathered via JS/HTML.

Comment: What you describe seems like a really straight forward thing to implement by parsing the different store pages. What have you tried?

Comment: Sure that is an option but the one I wanted to avoid. Maybe there is a 3rd party solution like jQuery plugin or RESTful service making such data available

Comment: Since we haven't found any alternative solution, we truly sticked to parsing the different stores web pages. yuck